# row rank = column rank over a PID?

Tags: linear-algebra, modules, matrix-rank

Suppose I have some matrix $M$ with entries from a PID. Define the column rank and row rank as you would expect: the rank of the module generated by the columns (resp. rows).

Is it always true that the column rank is equal to the row rank?

Comment: It seems to me that as long as the entries come from a PID you should be able to use elementary row operations to bring the matrix to echelon form, and then both the row rank and the column rank are given by the number of pivots (leading nonzero entries of rows).

Comment: Is the row rank or column rank of a matrix over a PID the same as the rank of the same matrix over the field of fractions?

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang good question - I would assume so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, due to the existence/uniqueness of [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form):

> For any PID $R$ and any $(n\times m)$-dimensional matrix $A$ with entries in $R$, it holds that $A$ is equivalent to a diagonal matrix $B$ with diagonal entries $\delta_1,\delta_2,\ldots,\delta_k,0,\ldots,0$, where the $\delta_i$ are nonzero elements of $R$ and $\delta_i|\delta_{i+1}$ for all $i<k$.

Equivalence of $A$ and $B$ here means there are invertible square matrices $P\in M_n(R)$ and $Q\in M_m(R)$ with $B=PAQ$. In particular the rank of the images of $A$ and $B$ agree, and similarly for the null spaces.